# jQuery to loop through elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a load of divs with the class `testimonial` and I want to use jquery to loop through them to check for each div if a specific condition is true. If it is true, it should perform an action.

Does anyone know how I would do this?

Answer (score 1361, accepted):

Use each: '`i`' is the postion in the array, `obj` is the DOM object that you are iterating (can be accessed through the jQuery wrapper `$(this)` as well).

```
$('.testimonial').each(function(i, obj) {
    //test
});
```

Check the [api reference](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for more information.

Comment: The function with i, obj parameters helps a lot. If just each was used then it was not iterating.

Comment: @Darwindeeds correct! The function is used by the actual iterator to process each item. Returning `false` will stop iteration.

Comment: It is worth pointing out, that "obj" will be the dom object, while $(this) is the jQuery object.

Comment: Cant we do jQuery(this 'ul li').length to get length of that elements ul li?

Comment: $(this).find('ul li').length will give you the nummer of li's that are within all the ul's in the current scope.

Comment: I like this approach because the loop is in a separate scope (function), so there's no `i` variable after this loop. Variable names can be re-used/shadowed inside the loop without breaking anything on the outside.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `$(this)` to access the object... `obj` being DOM object doesn't allow to attach functions directly for example `obj.empty()`

Comment: Worth noting that $.each('.testimonial', function(i, obj) { // do something } is NOT the same thing and will likely get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for" error.  (yes, I got that and found this way that works! :)

Comment: How to to this in JS?

Answer (score 168):

try this...

```
$('.testimonial').each(function(){
    //if statement here 
    // use $(this) to reference the current div in the loop
    //you can try something like...


    if(condition){

    }


 });
```

Comment: FYI: `break;` will not break. You must use `return false;`

Answer (score 72):

It's pretty simple to do this without jQuery these days.

### Without jQuery:

Just select the elements and use the [`.forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over them:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.testimonial');
Array.from(elements).forEach((element, index) => {
  // conditional logic here.. access element
});
```

In older browsers:

```
var testimonials = document.querySelectorAll('.testimonial');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(testimonials, function(element, index) {
  // conditional logic here.. access element
});
```

Answer (score 54):

Try this example

**Html**

```
<div class="testimonial" data-index="1">
    Testimonial 1
</div>
<div class="testimonial" data-index="2">
    Testimonial 2
</div>
<div class="testimonial" data-index="3">
    Testimonial 3
</div>
<div class="testimonial" data-index="4">
    Testimonial 4
</div>
<div class="testimonial" data-index="5">
    Testimonial 5
</div>
```

When we want to access those `divs` which has `data-index` greater than `2` then we need this jquery.

```
$('div[class="testimonial"]').each(function(index,item){
    if(parseInt($(item).data('index'))>2){
        $(item).html('Testimonial '+(index+1)+' by each loop');
    }
});
```

[**Working example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3xdq3Lb3/)

Answer (score 33):

you can do it this way

```
$('.testimonial').each(function(index, obj){
    //you can use this to access the current item
});
```

Answer (score 27):

I may be missing part of the question, but I believe you can simply do this:

```
$('.testimonial').each((index, element) => {
    if (/* Condition */) {
        // Do Something
    }
});
```

This uses jQuery's each method: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/

Answer (score 27):

[jQuery's .eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) can help you traverse through elements with an indexed approach.

```
var testimonialElements = $(".testimonial");
for(var i=0; i<testimonialElements.length; i++){
    var element = testimonialElements.eq(i);
    //do something with element
}
```

Comment: this is the most efficient approach indeed.

Comment: I like this because the element is a jQuery object.

Answer (score 20):

```
divs  = $('.testimonial')
for(ind in divs){
  div = divs[ind];
  //do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: that doesn't give you the jquery objects though, just dom elements

Comment: @celwell can't expect jQuery to do everything for you.  It is a matter of making your own jQuery Object `$(ind)`.

Answer (score 18):

With a simple for loop:

```
var testimonials= $('.testimonial');
for (var i = 0; i < testimonials.length; i++) {
  // Using $() to re-wrap the element.
  $(testimonials[i]).text('a');
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can do this concisely using [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). The following example will hide all .testimonial divs containing the word "something":

```
$(".testimonial").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf("something") !== -1;
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 10):

**Without jQuery updated**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.testimonial').forEach(function (element, index) {
    element.innerHTML = 'Testimonial ' + (index + 1);
});
```

```html
<div class="testimonial"></div>
<div class="testimonial"></div>
```

Comment: almost the same answer is already here, I think you should edit existing

Answer (score 10):

You could use the jQuery $each method to loop through all the elements with class testimonial.
i => is the index of the element in collection and val gives you the object of that particular element and you can use "val" to further access the properties of your element and check your condition.

```
$.each($('.testimonal'), function(i, val) { 
    if(your condition){
       //your action
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

In JavaScript **ES6** [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
over an *array-like* [**NodeList** collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) given by `Element.querySelectorAll()`

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".testimonial").forEach((el, idx) => {
  el.style.color = "red";
  console.log(`${idx} Element ${el.tagName} with ID #${el.id} says: ${el.textContent}` );
});
```

```html
<p class="testimonial" id="1">This is some text</p>
<div class="testimonial" id="2">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: The spread operator + array notation is not needed, surely doing `doc..torAll.forEach()` would suffice?

Comment: Thank you. Absolutely. `[...ArrayLike]` was used for the time querySelectorAll didn't had support for `.forEach`. @aabbccsmith

Answer (score 7):

```
$('.testimonal').each(function(i,v){
  if (condition) {
    doSomething();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

More precise:

```
$.each($('.testimonal'), function(index, value) { 
    console.log(index + ':' + value); 
});
```

Comment: This is nice if you like reading/writing from a more functional perspective.