# Difference in Jquery.each() and Array.prototype.forEach() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any difference between Jquery.each() and Array.prototype.forEach() method since array.forEach() method can also be used to loop over array-like objects with length property.The only difference i see is placement of arguments ,what else can be the difference in them?

```
 I found this:
 var obj = { one:1, two:2, three:3, four:4, five:5 };

jQuery.each(obj, function(i, val) {
  $("#" + i).append(document.createTextNode(" - " + val));
});
```

What i wan to know is ,do jquery.each() invokes function for object without length property??

Comment: Here's the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611190/what-is-the-difference-between-eachselector-and-selector-each

Comment: You changed your question. Now you're asking if jQuery's `$.each` is overloaded to enumerate any object. Why not just try it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Placement of arguments in the callback.
- Quantity of arguments in the callback (The `.forEach()` gives you get a reference to the original collection.)
- Default `this` value in the callback. (In jQuery it's the current item, in `.forEach()` it's the JavaScript default)
- Ability to manually set the `this` value in the callback. (jQuery doesn't give this option, `.forEach()` lets you via a third argument.)
- Avoidance of non-defined properties on sparse Arrays. (The `.forEach()` avoids them, jQuery includes them.)

---

They're very differently behaving methods. jQuery's doesn't make any attempt to be compliant with or complimentary of the standard behaviors.

Comment: What i wan to know is ,do jquery.each() invokes function for object without length property??

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Crazy Train's answer:

> What i wan to know is ,do jquery.each() invokes function for object without length property??

Read the source:

```
// args is for internal usage only
each: function( object, callback, args ) {
  var name, i = 0,
      length = object.length,
      isObj = length === undefined || jQuery.isFunction( object );

  if ( args ) {
    ...

  // A special, fast, case for the most common use of each
  } else {

    if ( isObj ) {
      for ( name in object ) {
      }
      ...
    }
  }
  return object;
},
```

So you can see if there is no length property, or it has the value *undefined*, then jQuery thinks it's a plain object and will do a for..in loop over the enumerable properties with no guard against inherited properties.