# In jQuery, what's the difference between these $.each declarations?

Tags: jquery

I have used both ways before but I'm not sure what the differences are. Could someone explain the differences?

```
1. $(myObjects).each(function(){}};

2. $.each($(myObjects), function(){});
```

Comment: NO worries, this question is clear.

Comment: Those aren't declarations. And not only has this been [asked and answered already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611190/what-is-the-difference-between-eachselector-and-selector-each), but there's the documentation ([`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **jQuery Object Iterator**

```
$('.myClass, .anotherClass').each(function(){}};
```

This is to loop over each jquery element, from your selector.

> **From the docs:**
>
> Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.
>   The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object.

[**.each() docs**](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

---

### **Generic iterator**

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
$.each(arr, function(index, value){});
```

This is a utility method to loop over an array or an object.

> **From the docs:**
>
> A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via their named properties.

[**$.each() docs**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

---

### **Difference:**

You can use both: $.each() and .each() to loop over a jQuery object list.

```
// Can be used to iterate any list or object
var $selectedElements = $('.tabs');
$.each($selectedElements, function(index, value){
    $(this).html(index);
});

// Can only be used for iterating a list of jquery objects, 
//  and is the recommended way of doing it.
$selectedElements.each(function(index, element){
    $(this).html(index);

});
```

But you cannot use .each() to loop over an object or list

```
// YOU CANNOT DO THIS
var list = [1,2,3];
list.each(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)**:

> The $.each() function is not the same as .each(), which is used to
>   iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The $.each() function can
>   be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is a map
>   (JavaScript object) or an array.

Answer (score 1):

.each is an iterator that is used to iterate over only jQuery objects collection while jQuery.each ($.each) is a general function for iterating over javascript objects and arrays.