# Get the text from all elements with the same class

Tags: jquery

In making a US map that displays store locations using [this map plug in](http://newsignature.github.com/) I've got it mostly nailed down but want a better way to perform one funciton. I have a list of stores below the map and want to group all stores in the same state and display the store names in a sidebar when you hover over the state. I have the hover and displaying of data working but want to improve. Instead of just writing a function for each state and explicitly stating what to display, I would like to get the first `p.cn` from each div that has the same class.

```
<div class="texas">
    <p class="cn">Store 1</p>
</div>

<div class="texas">
    <p class="cn">Store 2</p>
</div>

mouseoverState: {
    var texas = $('.texas > p.cn').text();
    $('#mysidebarID').html(texas);
}
```

This is only displaying the first store "store 1" I cannot get it to grab every `p.cn` from each div.texas and display them with a `<br>` after each one.

How do I get the html from every element with the same class and combine it into a string with each node separated by a `<br>`?

thank you - let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735342/jquery-to-loop-through-elements-with-the-same-class

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the `each()` method, try the following:

```
var str = "";

$('.texas > p.cn').each(function(){
  str += $(this).text() + "<br>";
})

$('#mysidebarID').html(str);
```

Comment: man that's the good stuff. Very much appreciated, and a lesson learned!

Comment: Long time Brother +1 `:)` old name is back Ramison `:P`

Comment: @Tats_innit _Raminson_? Who is he? `:P` Hey Bro, yes, long time `:)`

Comment: @undefined ha ha yea bruv, loooong time for me, good to see you! `:)`

Comment: How would you concantenate(sp?) the $('.texas > p.cn') with another p, p.tel without having to create another var and function and join that in the '#mysidebarID'.html(str newvar)?

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign Do you mean without the each loop? You can use the `eq` method for selecting the elements separately, then you can concatenate the strings by using `+=` operator or `+`.

Comment: @undefined - yeah i might want to build the listing with the phone number (p.tel) under the name (p.cn) Intellectually I almost understand what you stated above, in practice, Im not close.

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign You can post another question for this.