# How to loop through each image with the same class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery to loop through elements with the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735342/jquery-to-loop-through-elements-with-the-same-class)

I am trying to loop through my images that have a class.

```
for(var i=0; i<sizes.length; i++){
    var imageSize=sizes[i];
    $('.image').width(imageSize);
}
```

I have 10 images with the same class name, however, I want them to have different image size.

The loop will loop 10 times but I am not sure how to make each image has the specific `imagesize`.

Can anyone help me with it? My brain is almost fry. Thanks so much!

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. what is sizes and how many images to you have? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Remember: `$(selector)` matches *all elements with that selector*. So you have a collection of images which you're trying to set the width of, and jQuery obliges.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if all of your images have a class of `.image`, you can simply do the following

```
$( '.image' ).each( function ( index ) {
    $( this ).css( 'width', sizes[ index ] );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.image').each(function(i) {
    $(this).width(sizes[i]);
});
```

But you would have to make sure that the sizes array contains the correct sizes in the same order that the images appear on the page.