# Disable checkbox on table on load when there is specific value

Tags: php, jquery, html-table

I want to check the table row value on page load..

Table example:

**Name**  || **Status**  || **Set**

John || Pass || [ ] (checkbox)

Chris || Fail || [ ] (checkbox)

When the **status** is 'Fail' I want to disable the checkbox..

Now I'm using this **jQuery**:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  

    if(getElementsByClassName('paket_ava').value=='kosong'))
    {  
        document.getElementById("checkboxx").disabled=true;
    } 
});
</script>
```

and this is my **PHP table code** :

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $paket['id_paket'];?></td>                                   
    <td><?php echo $paket['nama_paket'];?></td>     
    <td><?php echo $paket['keterangan_paket'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $paket['harga'];?></td>
    <td><img src='<?php echo $paket['gambar_paket']?>' width='120' height='120'></td>
    <td  class="paket_ava"><?php echo $paket['ketersediaan_paket'];?></td>
    // class on the table data
    <td><?php echo $paket['status_harian_paket'];?></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkDel[]" id="checkboxx" class="aku" value="<?=$paket["id_paket"];?>"></td>
    <?php
         echo ("<td><a href='edit_data_paket.php?id_paket=$paket[id_paket]'>Edit</a></td>");        
    ?>
</tr>
```

The code above is not working, but if I change to:

```
if(getElementsByClassId('paket_ava').value=='kosong')) 
        {  
            document.getElementById("checkboxx").disabled=true;
        }
```

(of course I change the class in the table into Id)

When the page load its acting strange and the checkbox on the first data is disabled..

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below.... It will help you...

Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/68wbx/126/

Suppose your HTML Table was like below:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="datapaket" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Set</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td><td class="paket_ava">Pass</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkDel[]" id="checkboxx" class="aku" value='sam'/></td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Chris</td>
        <td class="paket_ava">Fail</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkDel[]" id="checkboxx" class="aku" value='sam'/></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

and try the Below Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('#datapaket tr').each(function() {    //Looping Every Table Row
      //Get the TD Value that have Classname ".paket_ava"
      var str = $(this).find('.paket_ava').html(); 
      if(typeof str !== 'undefined'){
        if (str.indexOf("Fail") >= 0)
        $(this).find('td:nth-child(3) input:checkbox').attr("disabled", true);
      };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

traverse through each element having class 'paket_ava' and do your stuff inside it. like

```
 $('.paket_ava').each(function(i, obj) {
// your stuff...
});
```

Reference : [jQuery to loop through elements with the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735342/jquery-to-loop-through-elements-with-the-same-class)