# Get html value from object within an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an exemplary JavaScript code snippet. What I'm trying to achieve here is getting html, and id attribute value from an object within the array

```
var swatches = $(".swatchColor");
for (var i = 0; i < swatches.length; i++) {
     var value = parseInt(swatches[i].html());
     if (!isNaN(value)) {
         alert(swatches[i].attr("id"));
     }
};
```

but for some reason I get Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error when swatches[i].html() is executed. Why does it happen?

Comment: Try `$(swatches[i]).html()`. As noted below though, `.each()` is the more common way of accomplishing this.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you should consider using its [each method](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: That was the answer. Thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery class selector does not provide an array of node elements for you to iterate through.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735342/jquery-to-loop-through-elements-with-the-same-class) answer, you need to do the following to iterate through all of the nodes:

```
$(".swatchColor").each(function(i, obj) {
    var value = parseInt($(obj).html());
    //etc...
});
```

Comment: That eventually worked for me, but had to change it to: var value = parseInt($(obj).html()); Please consider updating your answer, will mark it as an answer

Comment: `obj` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object. Your answer has the same problem as the original question.