# How to find if function is on or off

Tags: jquery, html, function

I have 5 elements with a class `foo`. and a function is attached with them like this

```
$('.foo').on('click',someFunction)
```

But for one of function is `off()`. I want to loop through these elements and find that element for which function is off. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean by "But for one of them function is off()"? Do you want to know which element doesn't have `someFunction` click handler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery to loop through elements with the same class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735342/jquery-to-loop-through-elements-with-the-same-class)

Comment: @Vohuman when I click one element with foo class, function runs `someFunction` and makes `$(this).off('click',someFunction)`. Now I want to get this clicked element.

Comment: `this` refers to that element. Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you unbind the handler the element is clicked, so `this` keyword already refers to that element! You can store the clicked elements in array or a jQuery collection using `jQuery.prototype.add` method and use them whenever you need.

Another option is an adding an identifier (e.g. a class name) to the element:

```
$(this).off('click', someFunction).addClass('bar');
```

Now you can simply get the target elements by using:

```
$('.foo.bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to this element in another function or somewhere else in the script, just use a global variable (either a string for the last or an array for all "click-ignoring" element/s) and store it in there maybe like this:

```
var lastClickedElement = "";
$(".foowrap .foo").each(function(){
    $(this).on("click", function(){
        $(this).off("click");
        lastClickedElement = $(this);
    });
});
```

or, if you don't want to store the whole element, you can just store it's index. to do so, replace `lastClickedElement = $(this);` with `lastClickedElement = $(this).index();`.
You could then just refer to it as `$(".foowrap .foo").index(lastClickedElement)`.