# jQuery to loop through dynamically created elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have no. of div which is created dynamically in button click.

```
<table>
   <tbody id="ProductDetail"></tbody>
</table>
```

In button click, some no. of div are created with Amount value.

```
funtion createDiv(){
  $("#ProductDetail").append("<tr><td ><div class='Amount'>"+Amount+"</div></td></tr>");
}
```

I want to loop through these dynamically created div to get Amount values in jquery.I tried below code. But its not iterating loop.

```
function calculateAmount(){
    $('.Amount').each(function (i, obj) {
         TotalAmountValue=TotalAmountValue+$(this).html();
    });
}
```

Please anybody help me.

Comment: can you include the js that you have tried so far?you can iterate through the div using class but i am not sure how you do it now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery to loop through elements with the same class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735342/jquery-to-loop-through-elements-with-the-same-class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this working just fine!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $("#ProductDetail").append("<tr><td><div class='Amount'>3</div></td></tr>");
          $("#ProductDetail").append("<tr><td><div class='Amount'>3</div></td></tr>");
          $("#ProductDetail").append("<tr><td><div class='Amount'>3</div></td></tr>");

          $("#sum").click(function()
          {
              var sum = 0;
              $(".Amount").each(function()
              {
                  sum += parseInt($(this).text());
              });
              alert(sum);
          });
      });
```

the `.each` iterates through all your elements that have the class `Amount`. Use the `.` selector for class and add the name.
Index represents the position, while the val is the current element.

Edit: get a local variable and set it to 0. After that, iterate through all the elements with that class and take their text. Since it is `String`, js will try to convert the `sum` variable to `String`. You need to parse the text to `int`. This is a working example.

Here is the HTML

```
  <table>
      <tbody id="ProductDetail"></tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="button" id="sum" value="Sum">
```

Comment: I tried these. But its not working.. these div is dynamically created

Comment: @sajbeer, what is the AmountValue doing in your function?

Comment: calculate the total amount value.. but its not getting in to function.

Comment: @sajbeer, you have the `$(document).ready` at the begining of the script?

Comment: @sajbeer, check it now. This should work, tried it on my own.

Comment: but in my case function calculateAmount() is outside the $(document).ready

Comment: @sajbeer, when is your function `calculateAmount called?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `text()`

```
$('.Amount').each(function (i, obj) {
  TotalAmountValue += parseInt($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.Amount').each(function(index, val)
    {
        //do something
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the **calculateAmount()** function right after **createDiv()** depending on your page weight, it might happen that the DIV you create on the fly it's not written to the DOM yet and your `each` function inside **calculateAmount()** it's not triggered. I recommend `adding a JS delay` to give the browser the time to append the divs to the DOM. For the user, it will make no difference.

HTML

```
<table>
   <tbody id="ProductDetail"></tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
function createDiv(){
  $("#ProductDetail").append("<tr><td ><div class='Amount'>"+Amount+"</div></td></tr>");
}

function calculateAmount(){
    $('.Amount').each(function (i, obj) {
         TotalAmountValue += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
}

createDiv();

setTimeout(function () {
    calculateAmount();
}, 400);
```