# jquery function on same classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where I have a table with a class. This table sometimes occurs multiple times on the page. I need to do the same jquery function on each instance. How do I achieve that with jquery...???

Here is my jquery:

```
jQuery(window).load(function () { 
    if(jQuery('.ezfc-summary-table tr:eq(2) td:eq(1)').text()=='1 layer'){
    jQuery('.ezfc-summary-table tr:eq(5)').hide();
    jQuery('.ezfc-summary-table tr:eq(6)').hide();
    jQuery('.ezfc-summary-table tr:eq(8)').hide();
}
});
```

@devlin carnate - i'm trying to do another thing, which is to take the text from one of the td's and append it to another class (product-title), which also appears multiple times. Here is what i have tried, but it only takes the text from the first td it finds, and appends it to all the following classes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ezfc-summary-table').each(function(i, obj) {
    var table = $(this);
    if (table.find('tr').eq(2).find('td').eq(1).text() == '1 layer') {
      table.find('tr').eq(5).hide();
      table.find('tr').eq(6).hide();
      table.find('tr').eq(8).hide();
var getpartname = $('.ezfc-summary-table tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)').text();
    $('.product-title').append('<span style="padding-left: 5px;">'+getpartname+'</span>');
    }
  });
});
```

Could you help me solve this problem also...???

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you have multiple different class names that you want to hide?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery to loop through elements with the same class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735342/jquery-to-loop-through-elements-with-the-same-class)

Comment: Using `.load()` to define an event handler is deprecated, use `.on('load', ...)' or `$(document).ready(...)`

Comment: Maybe you want all the elements with this selector:
`all_things = $('.ezfc-summary-table tr:eq(2) td:eq(1)');` then you can just loop through them if the length is greater than 1

Comment: just to be clear, Do you want to check each row td text, The one which contains ' layer 1 ' should remain visible and the remaining rows dissapear from display.

If i'm wrong please provide a code snippet or a js-fiddle to showcase your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the class assigned to the tables using `jQuery` [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and hide the rows based on whether the '1 layer' text condition is met:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ezfc-summary-table').each(function(i, obj) {
    var table = $(this);
    if (table.find('tr').eq(2).find('td').eq(1).text() == '1 layer') {
      table.find('tr').eq(5).hide();
      table.find('tr').eq(6).hide();
      table.find('tr').eq(8).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a Fiddle Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/f45umhkp/2/

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PCB-Tech : if this answers your question, you can mark it as the solution using the checkmark icon near the top of my answer.

Comment: could you please take a look at my updated question, thanks!

Comment: @PCB-Tech :  Technically, you should open a new question.  But, I'll give you a hint.  It looks like you're making the same mistake as you originally did.  My solution is looping through the tables and finding the rows.  You should use syntax that is **relative** to the scope inside the each loop.  `var partname = table.find('tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(1).text();`.  You then need to append that to the **relative** element with the `product-title` class.  I don't know the structure of your HTML elements, so I'll leave that part to you to figure out.  Think through what my solution above is doing.