# Unable to make individual divs in class draggable using jQuery .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, each, jquery-ui-draggable

### Problem Overview:

I am creating circular div elements to serve as location markers on a map. My code reads the total number of rows from a database table and executes a loop to create that number of div elements, assigning each a div id using data returned from the database. Each div element is appended to a single div class (marker_mother). All of this works perfectly, resulting in a row of circular div elements on the page.

The next step is to make each individual div element draggable. I am using the [.each() jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through all div elements in the class (marker_mother) and set them to draggable using the [Draggable interaction from the jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/). I have been using the following Stack Overflow Q&A as a reference: [jQuery to loop through elements with the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735342/jquery-to-loop-through-elements-with-the-same-class). However, all my attempts result in the class being set to draggable and not the individual divs. This means that all divs respond as a unified whole when dragged.

---

## Code:

```js
var total_units = "";

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Triggers PHP script to return number of table rows from DB

  $('#get_rows').click(function() {
    $.get('get_coords.php', function(data) {
      total_units = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
  });

  // Posts row number to DB and returns query data (eg. id and colour)
  // Uses returned data in construction of circular div elements

  $('#create_divs').click(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < total_units; i++) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'get_row.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
          row: i
        },
        success: function(response) {
          var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
          jQuery('<div/>', {
            id: jsonData.id,
            css: {
              "position": "relative",
              "top": "200",
              "left": "100",
              "border-radius": "50%",
              "width": "100px",
              "height": "100px",
              "background": "jsonData.colour",
              "font-size": "20px",
              "text-align": "center",
              "line-height": "100px",
              "cursor": "move",
              "z-index": "100"
            },
            href: 'http://127.0.0.1/' + jsonData.id + '.html',
            text: jsonData.id
          }).appendTo('.marker_mother');
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  // Assigns top&left positions of dragged div to variables
  // Code to store coords in db will be added later

  var coordinates = function(element) {
    element = $(element);
    var top = element.position().top;
    var left = element.position().left;
  }

  // Loops through divs and makes each draggable

  $('.marker_mother').each(function(index, item) {
    $(item).draggable({
      start: function() {
        coordinates(item);
      },
      stop: function() {
        coordinates(item);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/* CSS to define characteristics for the marker div class */

.marker_mother {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  line-height: 50px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

As mentioned in the overview, I have tried multiple implementations of the `.each()` function to make the divs draggable (including referring to the DOM object and `$(this)`). All attempts result in the class (`marker_mother`) being set to draggable and not the individual divs. I feel there must be something simple I am missing here.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

## Edit:

HTML markup for the created divs end up looking as follows:

```
<div class="marker_mother ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"> == $0
  <div id="0001" href="http://127.0.0.1/0001.html" style="position: relative; border-radius: 50%; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: lime; font-size: 20px; text-align: center; line-height: 100px; cursor: move; z-index: 100;">0001</div>
  <div id="0002" href="http://127.0.0.1/0002.html" style="position: relative; border-radius: 50%; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: lime; font-size: 20px; text-align: center; line-height: 100px; cursor: move; z-index: 100;">0002</div>
  <div id="0003" href="http://127.0.0.1/0003.html" style="position: relative; border-radius: 50%; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: lime; font-size: 20px; text-align: center; line-height: 100px; cursor: move; z-index: 100;">0003</div>
</div>
```

## Solution:

haydenwagner provided the solution in an answer below.

```
$('.marker_mother div').each(function(index, item) {
```

Comment: What does your html markup look like?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if you even need to loop over anything with `$.each()` to make this work

Comment: I have added the markup for the created divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like you are affecting the marker_mother element instead of its children (the divs that you appended).

Try changing this code:

```
$('.marker_mother').each(function(index, item) {
```

to this:

```
$('.marker_mother div').each(function(index, item) {
```

so that the elements that you are making draggable in the each function are the divs inside the .marker_mother element.

If this works then you can add a '.marker' or '.'marker-draggable' class to these divs so that your selection can be more explicit (with the code above, all divs inside the '.marker_mother' will become draggable). This may not be necessary if you are only appending draggable elements to the '.marker_mother' element.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work. Any other ideas? Your suggestion regarding the '.marker-draggable' class is a good one. In my case though, all divs in the '.marker_mother' class will be draggable.

Comment: can you make a codepen or fiddle that reproduces your problem? I think your problem has to do with which elements you are selecting to make draggable. As I said above, '$('.marker_mother').each' will make each marker_mother draggable (not what you want, because marker_mother is the container). You need to select the children of marker mother to make draggable--I tried to do this in the answer above, but it is hard to know exactly what the selector should be without seeing a live example of your code.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with the changed code: https://jsfiddle.net/dL2fnws8/8/

Comment: Here this is your fiddle edited: https://jsfiddle.net/oua3Lud1/19/ -- As you can see you want the selector as 'marker_mother div' so that they are the draggable elements. I passed $(this) instead of $(item) to the coordinates function because that was giving me an error in your fiddle (I think the 'item' var was left over from when you were using the each() method)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I got it working. I appreciate you sticking with me. I was trying to implement the code in a script with other functions and it wasn't executing. I then tied the execution of the function to a button with onclick() and was able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you looping through all elements with the class `marker_mother` instead of the children. But in this case you don't need the `$.each()` loop here.

Just tweak your selector and `draggable` can handle the rest:

```
// Assigns top&left positions of dragged div to variables
  // Code to store coords in db will be added later

  var coordinates = function(element) {
    var top = element.position().top;
    var left = element.position().left;
  }

  // Loops through divs and makes each draggable


  $('.marker_mother div').draggable({
    start: function() {
      coordinates($(this));
    },
    stop: function() {
      coordinates($(this));
    }
  });
```

---

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/L9nk17n6/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the input @empiric but your code isn't working for me. Once I make the changes none of the divs are draggable.

Comment: @mycognosist you might be missing something. Can you provide an example with the changed code? In fact I used the code provided by you to make my changes and it works in the example.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with the changed code: https://jsfiddle.net/dL2fnws8/8/