# Check if input is empty, if not, add class to parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a number of inputs like this:

```
<div class="fg-line">
    <input type="text" class="form-control fg-input place-edit placeInformation" id="place_name">
    <label class="fg-label">Place Name</label>
</div>
<div class="fg-line">
    <input type="text" class="form-control fg-input place-edit placeInformation" id="place_address">
    <label class="fg-label">Place Address</label>
</div>
```

I get some data from an API and then append to these inputs (so the user can edit).

This works fine. The issue is that I want to add a class to this:

```
<div class="fg-line">
```

This is simple enough if I only have one of these and one input, but since I have multiple, I need some way to check each input and if not empty add the class `fg-toggled` such that the line becomes:

```
<div class="fg-line fg-toggled">
```

If I had just one input, I'd do this:

```
if (('#place_name').value != '' || ('#place_name').value != ('#place_name').defaultValue) {
  $('.fg-line').addClass('fg-toggle')
}
```

But I don't know how to do this without writing this out for every class (there are 30+). Is there a way to iterate this somehow? I tried checking `.place-edit` but since it's a class, if any of the inputs with the class are not empty then they all get the new class added.

Comment: yes, you can iterate by selecting `class`. see this for help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735342/jquery-to-loop-through-elements-with-the-same-class

Comment: @tech2017 yes, but what am i testing? Don't I still have to check every id (`place_name`, etc) first? That's the tricky part (to me anyway.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply loop through each input and find the parent using .closest().

```
$('.placeInformation').each(function() {
    var $input = $(this);

    if ($input.val()) {
        var $parent = $input.closest('.fg-line');
        $parent.addClass('fg-toggled')
    }

});
```

[Sample plunkr](https://jsfiddle.net/x7Lwoxwk/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Can use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('.fg-line').has('.placeInformation').filter(function(){
   return !$(this).find('.placeInformation').val()
}).addClass('fg-toggled')
```

Not sure what *"default"* should be or how it is declared. Could be set in a data attribute and add an `||` to above filter condition

Answer (score 1):

Use each() and closest() 
Try this :

```js
$(".fg-input").each(function() {

  if ($(this).val() != '') {
    $(this).closest(".fg-line").addClass('fg-toggle');
  }
})
```

```css
.fg-toggle
{
color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fg-line">
  <input type="text" class="form-control fg-input place-edit placeInformation" id="place_name">
  <label class="fg-label">Place Name</label>
</div>
<div class="fg-line">
  <input type="text" class="form-control fg-input place-edit placeInformation" id="place_address">
  <label class="fg-label">Place Address</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This adds the `fg-toggle` class to every `fg-line` as though the `if` statement always evaluates as `true`, but my inputs are empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through the `.place-edit` class and then check the values and add the class to the parents, like this:

```
$('.place-edit').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() != '' || $(this).val() != $(this).defaultValue) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('fg-toggle');
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.. I'm assuming they all have the same class

```
 if (('#place_name').value != '' || ('#place_name').value != ('#place_name').defaultValue) {
  $('.fg-line').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('fg-toggle')
  });
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I don't want to write this out 35 times since I have all different ids (`#place_name`)

Comment: if you dont want repeat 35 times, can get input similar to:

$('.fg-line').each(function(){
 if($(this).find('input').val() !== '')
    $(this).addClass('fg-toggle')
  });

or similary

Comment: You need get the parent class and get input  of parent class and apply conditional if are true go ahead to addClass similar of i write