# How can I iterate over a list of check boxes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for (var chkbox in jQuery("#dialog-message input[type='checkbox']")) {
    alert(chkbox.val() + " " + chkbox.is("checked"));
}
```

is not working; I get errors saying that `val` and `is` are undefined. I'd like to iterate over the check boxes inside the `dialog-message` element so I can see which ones are checked and execute some other code for the ones that are, but these errors are happening instead.

Comment: The proper jQuery way is [`.each(...)`](https://api.jquery.com/each/). Inside the function, use `$(this)` to do something with the current element.

Comment: What is your end-goal? If you're trying to get only the checked inputs, you don't need to iterate over them - just use the [`:checked` selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery to loop through elements with the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735342/jquery-to-loop-through-elements-with-the-same-class)

Comment: For reference, using `of` instead of `in` and `$(chkbox)` instead of `chkbox` will fix your code.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, the question Chris linked to doesn't concern how to use for...in/of loops. This question and selected answer adds useful info.

Comment: @t1m0thy The duplicate answers the question, that's what counts. Using `for ... in` on a jQuery object won't work properly anyway; are you suggesting a duplicate has to address a wrong approach to solving the problem at hand? It sure doesn't.

Comment: Not if you read past the headline. The "duplicate" asks "how?" this asks "why doesn't this work?" This question invites additional information and discussion on another way of approaching the task. The other could be considered PART OF this question. Part of something cannot be considered a duplicate of the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for...in` does not behave as you're expecting.

In your case, `chkbox` is **not** the checkbox element; it is an integer representing the index of the item in the collection. Integers have neither a `.value` nor a `.checked` property, hence the `undefined` error.

Instead, use jQuery's [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```js
$("#dialog-message input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
  console.log(`${this.value} is checked: ${this.checked}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog-message">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" checked />
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" checked />
</div>
```

**However**, if your goal is to get a collection of only the checked (or unchecked) elements, you don't need to iterate through them; you can select them using the [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector (or `:not(:checked)` for unchecked):

```js
$("#dialog-message input[type=checkbox]:checked").css("zoom", "2");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog-message">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" checked />
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" checked />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, using the `each` method and the `:checked` selector worked!

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery.each() function: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
jQuery.each(jQuery("#dialog-message input[type='checkbox']"), function(index, chkbox) {
  alert(chkbox.val() + " " + chkbox.is("checked"));
});
```

Comment: With your code, `chkbox` is an HTMLInputElement, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has .each()

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

`$('div').each(function(idx){ console.log(idx, this) })`

`this` being the current element. An advantage of using $.each here is arguably cleaner, more readable code and you also get the benefit of chaining.

However it is worth noting (although probably not relevant for your example) that a for loop will most likely perform (much)better when iterating over large collections of elements. For example you could write it like this;

```
let test = $('input'); 
for(let i = 0; i < test.length; i++){ 
    console.log(test[i].checked) 
}
```

Further, for...in will work but 1) `chkbox` will be the index of the checkbox in the collection and 2) unlike my first `for...` example where i will always be an integer index, `for...in` this will loop over all properties of the returned JQuery object. You can use `hasOwnProperty(i)` to filter out inherited properties like this;

```
test = $('input'); 
for(let i in test){ 
    if(!test.hasOwnProperty(i)) { 
        continue ; 
    } 
    console.log(test[i].checked) 
}
```