# jquery font color script based on value contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple if else statement that will color a number based on it's value.

Can anyone explain why the below always results in red?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // the following will select all elements with class "deltadiff"
    // if the element has a '-', it will assign a 'red' class, else it will assign the 'green class'

    if ($(".deltadiff:contains('-')"))
      $(".deltadiff").addClass('red');
    else $(".deltadiff").addClass('green');
  }

)
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<font class="deltadiff" style="font-size:10px; vertical-align:super;"> -120</font>

<font class="deltadiff" style="font-size:10px; vertical-align:super;"> 120</font>

<font class="deltadiff" style="font-size:10px; vertical-align:super;"> 5</font>

<font class="deltadiff" style="font-size:10px; vertical-align:super;"> -7</font>
```

Comment: You're not iterating over the elements. You have to use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to handle them individually. You are currently finding at least one with a `-`, then set all of them to red accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Chris, sorry new to Javascript, where do i put the .each()

Comment: You can do this: https://jsfiddle.net/7zw01L9b/

Comment: Thank you @ChrisG!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if ($(".deltadiff:contains('-')"))` only checks for the first element that has `deltadiff` as classname.

You should [loop through all the elements with the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735342/jquery-to-loop-through-elements-with-the-same-class).

Then, use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check if the `innerHTML` contains an `-`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // For each element with class: 'deltadiff'
    $('.deltadiff').each(function(i, obj) {
      
        // if the element has a '-', it will assign a 'red' class, else it will assign the 'green class'
        if (obj.innerHTML.includes('-')) {
            obj.classList.add("red");
        } else {
            obj.classList.add("green");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<font class="deltadiff" style="font-size:10px; vertical-align:super;"> -120</font>

<font class="deltadiff" style="font-size:10px; vertical-align:super;"> 120</font>

<font class="deltadiff" style="font-size:10px; vertical-align:super;"> 5</font>

<font class="deltadiff" style="font-size:10px; vertical-align:super;"> -7</font>
```