# How to add class to an element using its existing class name when there are multiple elements having same class name in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm calling a function on Click event to add a CSS class to an item in the list of elements with same class name.

**Here's what I'm trying to achieve**
On the click of the button, I want to add the class .active to a particular logo image. Let's say at index 0 or 1

Please help me fix the issue.

```js
document.ready(function() {
  function setActive() {
    $(".logo-slider .logos .logo")[0].addClass("active");
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.1/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="setActive()">Mark Active </button>
<div class="logo-slider">
  <div class="logos row">
    <div class="col"><img class="logo" src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" /></div>
    <div class="col"><img class="logo" src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/f4ffff/150x150.png" /></div>
    <div class="col"><img class="logo" src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ff6fff/150x150.png" /></div>
    <div class="col"><img class="logo" src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" /></div>
    <div class="col"><img class="logo" src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" /></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: add an id="" instead and use it to find the element

Comment: `onclick="setActive"` you didn't call the function. change it to `onclick="setActive()"`

Comment: If you're using jQuery, don't use `onclick`; use jQuery's `on('click`, ...` Also, when you use indexers on jQuery objects, you get an `HTMLElement` back, which does not have an `addClass` function. Use `eq()` instead.

Comment: The code snippet is producing an error because of variable scope.  Have you checked your console for errors and attempted to resolve those errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery to loop through elements with the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735342/jquery-to-loop-through-elements-with-the-same-class)

Comment: Also, `addClass` is a jQuery method, but `[0]` gets you the reference to the DOM element. You need to either proceed with DOM methods to add the class from there; wrap this into `$(...)` again first to get a jQuery object; or use https://api.jquery.com/eq/ instead of `[x]`

Comment: I think you should add a script code inside <script></script> tag

Comment: reinventing radio buttons

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nth-child()` css property to select specific element. Check snippet below..

```js
function setActive() {
    $(".logo-slider .logos .col:nth-child(2) .logo").addClass("active");
  }
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.1/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="setActive()">Mark Active </button>
<div class="logo-slider">
  <div class="logos row">
    <div class="col"><img class="logo" src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" /></div>
    <div class="col"><img class="logo" src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/f4ffff/150x150.png" /></div>
    <div class="col"><img class="logo" src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ff6fff/150x150.png" /></div>
    <div class="col"><img class="logo" src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" /></div>
    <div class="col"><img class="logo" src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" /></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. Your comments were helpful. I found an alternate solution.

Here's how I did it.

```
$(".logo-slider .logos .logo")[0].classList.add("active");
```

Got this idea after reading some of your comments.
Thanks.